# Express get sub-domain name

Tags: node.js, express

is there a way to use the express router to get the variable of the subdomain.

Lets say I have `foo.example.com` how can I get an output of `foo`.

Thanks

Comment: which version of express are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Express 4.x you can use `req.subdomains` property.

```
// Host: "tobi.ferrets.example.com"
req.subdomains
// => ["ferrets", "tobi"]
```

ref.: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.subdomains

Answer (score 2):

Express 4.x comes [req.subdomains](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.subdomains) but if you are using older version or want to play your own code then can be used other framework as well then you may like

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var host = req.get('host');
    console.log(getSubdomain(host));
    console.log(getSubdomainList(host));
    next();
})

function getSubdomain(host) {
    var subdomain = host ? host.substring(0, host.lastIndexOf('.')) : null;
    return subdomain;
}

function getSubdomainList(host) {
    var subdomainList = host ? host.split('.') : null;
    if(subdomainList)
        subdomainList.splice(-1, 1);
    return subdomainList;
}
```